# How to load Facebook/Twitter (say Google Facebook page) comments into MarkLogic Database

Tags: rss, feed, marklogic, marklogic-8

I want to load/insert/import comments form Twitter/Facebook page into MarkLogic database. Assume I have a Google Facebook page where when any comments are made on any posts, I want to load/import/insert those comments into MarkLogic Database.

If that page requires any permissions or rights from Facebook or Twitter, then I can acquire those rights.

Please share the idea of doing it or any related documentations/tutorials/GitHub projects which can make this work.